# How to get specific index values and store in a array from multiple php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I've multiple arrays received from db table. now i'm trying to check "is their birth date == current date" if yes then their contact numbers saved in a array called **birthdays**

**Here is my try**

```
$curr_date = date('m/d');

$birthday = array(); // array initialization
$anniversary = array(); // array initialization

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","birthdays");


$sql="SELECT * FROM users";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<pre>";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        print_r ($row);
    }
}
```

**Here is a image of current code with expected description**

[image]

I'm trying lot of time but unable to achieve exact result. kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: just look whats inside result['birth_date']

Comment: Where are you comparing birth date with current date?

Comment: ok, its genrates dates. now how can i check them from current date?

Comment: What are you doing? You run the query, fetch the first row, then run the query again and start fetching rows in a loop. Start by applying some sanity to your existing code

Comment: this is my actually issue @NanaPartykar. where am i compare this :/

Comment: i'm new to php @RiggsFolly, i'm not sure where i am wrong...!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this?

```
$date1 = date('m-d', strtotime($row['birth_date']));
$date2 = date('m-d');

if ($date1 == $date2)   {
    echo 'Happy birthday!';
}
```

See [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you got a result from the database, so you pull all the results in an array:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM xyztable";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$users = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[] = $row;
}
```

So now we are at the same point.
Now you can do a loop trough the arrays, create a Birthdays array and you should explode the birth date:

```
$birthdays = array();
for($users as $user) {
  $birth = explode("/", $user['birth_date']);

  $new_birth = "$birth[0]/$birth[1]";
  $actual_date = date("m/d");
  if($new_birth == $actual_date) {
     $birthdays[] = $user['customer_mobile'];
  }
}
```

That should be it.

Comment: unable to achieve with it..!

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only purpose of fetching data from database then there is no need to push these rows in a separate array. Just push the contact numbers to the array. There is no need to loop it twice.

```
    $curr_date = date('m/d');

    $birthday = array(); // array initialization
    $anniversary = array(); // array initialization

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","birthdays");


    $sql="SELECT * FROM users";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if (date('m/d',strtotime($row['birth_date'])) == $curr_date)
                $birthday[] = $row['customer_mobile'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: birthday

Comment: its says $birthday is undefined, when i print_r($birthday) bellow your code.

Comment: If the you wish to push the contact numbers to the `$birthdays` array which you have initialized then change the array to `$birthdays`, but if you have that array for some other purpose then initialize `$birthday = array()` where you have initialized other two arrays. I have updated the answer to push the contact numbers to the `$birthdays` array which you have initialized.

Comment: but why it says $birthdays is undefined..!

Comment: obviously, it says:

 Undefined index: birth_date

Comment: Can you print_r($row), and check whether there is `birth_date` index in every array? The screenshot that you have included shows that every $row array has `birth_date` index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148509/discussion-between-ravi-and-devendra-singh).